# Как лучше работать с сложными типами являющимися дженериками

Tags: c#, ооп, generics, интерфейс

Есть класс:

```
public class Resource<T> : IGame where T : Component 
{
```

И например мы его как тип используем в каком то интерфейсе:

```
public interface IBuildResource
{
    Resource<Component> GetPath(List<Resource<Component>> RefList);
}
```

Приемлемой ли практикой будет писать `<Resource<Component>>` заместо `<Resource<T>>` и соотвественно делать дженериком сам интерфейс.

Или например в функциях класса реализующих этот интерфейс писать:

```
class BuildComponent<T> : BaseCls, IBuildResource 
{
        public Resource<Component> GetPath(List<Resource<Component>> resList)
        {
            Resource<Component> resReference = null;
            . . .
            return resReference;
        }
```

Comment: приемлимо делать все, что сможет понять компилятор. если не упало с ошибкой - значит приемлимо :)

Comment: автор имеет в виду приемлемые практики использования? в чём критерии приемлемости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последний пример с `BuildComponent<T>` скорее всего неверен, так как выглядит это примерно так:

```
List<int> list;
list.Remove("item");
list.Find<String>()
```

Обычно такие методы всё-таки имеют какую-либо связь с `T`

```
public Resource<T> GetPath(List<Resource<T>> resList) where T : Component
```

Честно говоря, я бы крепко подумал над вложенными Generic'ами. Их просто неудобно читать и писать. Вместо `List<Resource<Component>>` я бы предпочёл видеть

```
class ComponentList : ResourceList<Component>
{
}

class ResourceList<T> : List<Resource<T>>
{
}
```

Это не потребует много сил и времени, из лишнего кода - только необходимость объявить конструкторы, зато код станет на порядок чище и приятнее глазу. Исключительно субъективное мнение. Некоторые использует вместо этого алиасы, но мне кажется, что они скорее запутают, чем помогут. А типизированных макросов у нас пока нет, в отличии от того же [Nemerle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemerle).

Comment: Мне тоже не нравится подобная практика, но к сожалению это код который нужно супортить и все переделать в более читабельный вариант не представляется возможным.

Comment: А почему, если не секрет? В предложенном выше варианте ты можешь передать `ComponentList` в метод, который принимает `List<Resource<Component>>` благодаря наследованию, а массовые правки легко осуществляются благодаря рефакторингам `ReSharper`'а.

Comment: Потому что в больших проектах с большим кол-вом человек нельзя вот так вот взять и что то поменять, менять можно только строго оговоренные места ))

Comment: Пойду к своему маленькому проекту на 200 разработчиков. :D